# Create a chain of transitions using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have created a little jQuery function with the help of [transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) that applies a transition to an element, and then to the next element after the transition is done.

The code applies the transition ony by one to whatever element is inside the `.container` div.

You can see the code in action here:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    showDiv($('.container div:first'));

    function showDiv(tadaa) {
        tadaa.transition({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, function () {
            //call back
            showDiv(tadaa.next());
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    border: 2px solid;
}

.container *{
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.container div {
    background-color: black;
}

.container p {
    background-color: red;
}

.container span {
    background-color: green;
}

.container input{
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
<div></div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
  <p></p>
  <div></div>
  <input>
  <div></div>
  <p></p>

</div>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this with jQuery but without using transit.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with jQuery alone just change `transition()` to `animate()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showDiv($('.container div:first'));

  function showDiv(tadaa) {
    tadaa.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000, function() {
      //call back
      showDiv(tadaa.next());
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container * {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container div {
  background-color: black;
}

.container p {
  background-color: red;
}

.container span {
  background-color: green;
}

.container input {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
  <p></p>
  <div></div>
  <input>
  <div></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```